# iOS swift recorded video deleted but app data still big

Tags: ios, swift

I developed recording video for some app but issue is when I delete one or all video app data stay same. And it's always increased when new video is recorded. Because app create video 720p and 1080p app data very quick  become few GB. That's not problem when videos are in photos but when user delete video app data doesn't go down. So, app will make memory issue. How to resolve this? I write in swift 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I remove all video with PHPhotoLibrary because I am also adding video with this api. So, I now also delete with FileManager and now it works :)